# List of items at normal line spacing

Tags: spacing, lists, miktex, line-spacing

It's been a while, but in TeXWorks I'm making a list of items. The long way:

```
\textbullet\hspace*{0.2cm} Jam
\textbullet\hspace*{0.2cm} Custard
\textbullet\hspace*{0.2cm} Beef
\textbullet\hspace*{0.2cm} Good
```

Don't do that, make it a list! I hear you cry, so I do:

```
\begin{itemize}
  \item Jam
  \item Custard
  \item Beef
  \item Good
\end{itemize}
```

However, when I create a list of the above the line spacing is not the same as ordinary lines of text. And since space is a premium in this document I'd like to know if there an easy way to keep the line spacing as normal as possible (like the first bit of .tex), but make the latex code easier on the eyes without adding a text bullet and horizontal spacing each line?

Comment: `\itemsep=0pt` either directly or (more easily) using `enumitem` package.

Comment: With `enumitem`, you set the option `[noitemsep] `. If furthermore, you want no vertical separation with the surrounding text, use `[nosep]`.

Answer (score 1):

Just for fun:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}

\def\arraystretch{1}% redundant, default
\begin{tabular}{@{\textbullet\hspace{0.2cm}}l}
  Jam \\
  Custard \\
  Beef \\
  Good
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

Comment: `tabular` does not allow page breaks in or between rows. `itemize` does allow page breaks in and between items.